# How to bind data to primeng table in angular2

Tags: angular

Hai i am using primeng table, now i need to bind values to html, but facing an error as

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I am not getting where i am going wrong.

HTML:

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="tableHeaders" [value]="Medication">
              <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr role="row">
                  <th>data1</th>
                  <th>data2</th>
                  <th>data3</th>
                  <th>data4</th>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
                  <td>{{rowData.data1}}</td>
                  <td>{{rowData.data2}}</td>
                  <td>{{rowData.data3}}</td>
                  <td>{{rowData.data4}}</td>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
            </p-table>
```

TS:

```
Medication: any[];
getEmrExportList() {
    let params = { 'Id': this.userId }
    this.emrService.getExportDetails(params)
      .subscribe(exportLists => {
        this.emrExportToCCDList = exportLists.Body.Data;
        this.Medication = this.emrExportToCCDList.Medication;
      })
  }
```

Console:
console.log(this.emrExportToCCDList);

```
{Device: {…}, Medication: {…}, Immunize: {…}}
Device: {DeviceName: "scissore", DeviceSuppliedDate: "2018-10-09T18:30:00.000Z"}
Immunize: {VaccineCode: "DTaP, 5 pertussis antigens", Status: "entered-in-error", Date: null}
Medication: {data1: "medication1", data2: "2018-08-15T18:30:00.000Z", data3: "instruction1", data4: "Active"}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: can you add your `*ngFor` code?

Comment: i have not used *ngFor anywhere, only so much i have added

Comment: your question and error code says otherwise

Comment: ya that only i am not getting, how it is coming, may be because, in value i had assigned Medication

Comment: @mast3rd3mon `*ngFor` is certainly used in the primeng component

Comment: Update your question with **Array**

Comment: What error you have got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are binding `object` while it requires `array`.

Make sure `this.emrExportToCCDList.Medication` is array of objects in this line.

```
this.Medication = this.emrExportToCCDList.Medication;
```

Medication should be something similar to:

```
this.Medication = [
    {
        data1: 'data1',
        data2: 'data2',
        data3: 'data3',
        data4: 'data4'
    },
    ...
]
```

If you are receiving only one object from server, you can do something like:

```
this.Medication = [];
this.Medication.push(this.emrExportToCCDList.Medication);
```

So modified code would be:

```
getEmrExportList() {
    let params = { 'Id': this.userId }
    this.emrService.getExportDetails(params)
        .subscribe(exportLists => {
            this.emrExportToCCDList = exportLists.Body.Data;
            this.Medication = [];
            this.Medication.push(this.emrExportToCCDList.Medication);
        })
}
```

Comment: ya but it is coming in this way {
        data1: 'data1',
        data2: 'data2',
        data3: 'data3',
        data4: 'data4'
    } so the error is occuring, can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

**ngFor** is used to loop through iterable types only. You can not use it to loop through object like `{data1: "medication1", data2: "2018-08-15T18:30:00.000Z", data3: "instruction1", data4: "Active"}`.

You have used **primeng table** which internally uses **ngFor** on your **value** input which is **Medication**.

your **Medication** variables value must be array like below :

```
[
  {
    data1: "medication1",
    data2: "2018-08-15T18:30:00.000Z",
    data3: "instruction1",
    data4: "Active"
  },
  {
    data1: "medication2",
    data2: "2018-08-15T18:30:00.000Z",
    data3: "instruction2",
    data4: "InActive"
  }
]
```